# Socket c# chat over internet?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am having trouble with sockets connecting from an external source

See below my constructor.

//Using UDP sockets

```
clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                          SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
EndPoint ourEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1450);
//Listen asynchronously on port 1450 for coming messages (Invite, Bye, etc).
clientSocket.Bind(ourEP);

//Receive data from any IP.
EndPoint remoteEP = (EndPoint)(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));

byteData = new byte[1024];
//Receive data asynchornously.
clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData,
                           0, byteData.Length,
                           SocketFlags.None,
                           ref remoteEP,
                           new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                           null);
```

this is connect button function:

```
private void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the IP we want to connect.
    otherPartyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtCallToIP.Text), 1450);
    otherPartyEP = (EndPoint)otherPartyIP;
}
```

I make chat application peer to peer over internet. i opened port 1450 firewall and add port forward but it's not connecting. Please can you help?

Comment: You will need to make your question clearer. Do you get any error messages? Or does it just fail to connect? Has it ever worked?

Comment: yes. it's run ok on local machine. but run over internet it not connect

Comment: Have you verified that at least ping works between these IPs?

Comment: i have access SqlServer over internet on port 1433 outside the network.
but with chat application i opened port 1450 but it's not connect

Comment: when i run app in local network is ok

Comment: UDP is connectionless transport. Do you send anything from the client? Show that sending code.

Comment: What does "not connecting" mean?  If you get exceptions, please detail them.  All you show in btnCall_Back is something that assigns to variable, nothing about connecting--show code that does the sending.  not enough information to tell you what's wrong (or right).

Comment: Thanks i haved fix it, because i'm seem config port fail

Answer (score 0):

When working with UDP you must ensure that the amount of HOPS a packet can travel is set correctly.

I'm not all to sure but I think the default is either 0 or 1.

Use the Ttl property on your socket to experiment with this. Try setting it to 10, if you are testing on a very short path.

Alternatively set it higher byt take care as the ttl property for datagrams denote the amount of points/routers (actually hops) the packet can travel trhough to reach its destination.

The value range can be from 0 to 255.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't think this is likely to be an issue here.

Comment: Thanks everyone help, problem of me is i has opened port 1450 with TCP. a bit confusion. i must open port 1450 with UDP. i has fix